# Android Radio Button Icon is too small/tiny in tablet (7" or 10" inches), but normal in Mobile Device

Tags: android, radio-button, android-xml, android-tablet-layout

Here is the XML code for the `RadioButton`.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:buttonTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="@string/largest_discount"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

I haven't added any custom icons/button for this RadioButton. Using the default colour and style of the RadioButton. But the **icon looks too tiny/small of the RadioButton in Tablet**, it looks normal and decent in Mobile device. Here is the attached image. The left one is the Tablet and the right side is a Mobile device. Clearly seen that Tablet icon is too small.

Do let me know what's wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You've scaled your emulator down in size (you can tell by looking at the navigation bar icons - the back, home, and recents button should be the exact same size). Both checkboxes will be the same physical size on actual devices.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I think that this is a general problem with Android that RadioButtons (for whatever strange reason) do not scale and become tiny when using tables. I had a question about this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537708/how-to-scale-the-circle-in-radiobuttons-in-android) and I was told that this is a problem of the Android platform in general. It has nothing to do with the scale of the emulator